# texlive langczechslovak collection compilation error

Tags: texlive, compiling, languages

I am trying to get this compiled. As I can see the upstream SVN repo this collections depends on the `csplain` package I am getting the error:

```
Loading UK English hyphenation patterns in ASCII encoding, \engbPatt=101 (engb)
.
! I can't find file `hyph-en-gb'.
<argument> \input hyph-en-gb
```

How to I get rid of this if I do not really want to install english language collection? And why does cz/sk coleection want en-gb macro being installed at all?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Currently your question is not fully clear. What are you trying to compile? A small example document that shows your issue would be helpful to clarify your question and possibly provide answers. Further questions: how do you compile (local installation or online, which compiler, which LaTeX distribution, which operating system)? What is the reason you don't want to install the English language definitions?

Comment: @Marijn, this is happening during from scratch compilation, not during doc compilation (compilation of the collection I mean). The problem is that if I want only instal czechoslovak macros, why should I install english ones, also once english ones are installed it requires italian ones with `! I can't find file hyph-it'.`

Comment: How do you compile exactly? Using `apt install texlive-lang-czechslovak`? Or some other way? Maybe you can make a selection of the CTAN packages from https://packages.debian.org/sid/tex/texlive-lang-czechslovak that you actually need, install these from CTAN, and leave the rest? Or just install `texlive-lang-all`, that may solve the problem as well.

Comment: @Marijn, this is actual gentoo ebuild https://gitweb.gentoo.org/repo/gentoo.git/tree/dev-texlive/texlive-langczechslovak/texlive-langczechslovak-2019.ebuild

Comment: In that case you could try to ask the Gentoo community, I'm not sure many people here can help you with this - most will say 'just use `tlmgr`' (which you could try of course).